# How to make ListView clickable in flutter?

Tags: listview, flutter

I'm loading data from api into my class UserProductType `List<UserProductType> _visibleUserProductTypes = api();`. Then I'm using ListView.builder to create cards that have child GestureDetector so I can register clicks. (Then I would like to change card background and once button is pressed, sent the one chosen id to other function...)

The problem is that this code is not calling the function `onTap: () => selectItem(product),`

Relevant part of the code:

```
  void selectItem(UserProductType product) {
      print(product.name);
  }

  Container listSection() {
    return Container(
        child: Expanded(
          child: ListView.builder(
            itemCount: _visibleUserProductTypes.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              var product = _visibleUserProductTypes[index];
              return new Card(
                elevation: 2,
                child: GestureDetector (
                  onTap: () => selectItem(product),
                  child: Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                    child: Row(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Icon(_icons[index], color: Colors.grey,),
                        SizedBox(width: 10.0,),
                        Text(_visibleUserProductTypes[index].name,
                          style: TextStyle(color: _colors[index]),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
        )
    );
  }
```

Where is the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrap the entire `Card` widget in a `GestureDetector` widget. The code below should solve your issue:

```
return GestureDetector(
    onTap: () => selectItem(product),
    child: Card(
        elevation: 2,
        child: Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
            child: Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                    Icon(_icons[index], color: Colors.grey,),
                    SizedBox(width: 10.0,),
                    Text(
                        _visibleUserProductTypes[index].name,
                        style: TextStyle(color: _colors[index]),
                    ),
                ],
            ),
        ),
    ),
);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ListTile` instead of `Card`.

```
return ListTile(
  onTap: () => selectItem(product),
  leading: Icon(_icons[index], color: Colors.grey),
  title: Text(_visibleUserProductTypes[index].name,
    style: TextStyle(color: _colors[index]),
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

tapping the container inside the card might execute the function. or just make the gesture detector on the card and the hit on the tap which can give you the desired output